# How to obtain substring from full string?

Tags: c

I have to try and use the GetSubstring function to print the result so that

```
printf(GetSubstring("character", 4, 3, resultArray));
```

outputs `act`

Limitations: can't call other functions or macros, can't add any other variables, can't set variable to 0. Can only change function GetSubstring.

Here is my current code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char *GetSubstring(const char source[], int start, int count, char result[]);

int main(void)
{
const char source[] = "one two three";
char result[] = "123456789012345678";

puts(GetSubstring("character", 4, 3, result));

return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}


char *GetSubstring(const char source[], int start, int count, char result[])
{
    char *copy = result;
    for (; *source != '\0' || *source == source[start]; start--)
    {
        while (*source != '\0')
        {
        *result++ = *source++;
        }

    }

    *result = '\0';
    return (copy);                                      // outputs character
    // return (result);                                 // outputs 012345678
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: return (copy); followed by return(result); <~ strangest bit of code I've seen since this morning! return(result) will never be reachable

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish using both a *for* and a *while* loop?  Your intended logic is murky.

Comment: Can you assume that the inputs to GetSubstring are valid or should the implementation be coded as defensively as possible?

Comment: I just wanted to show what the return is if I use result or copy. The for and while loop are there because I wasn't sure if I would need the  while loop so as a failsafe kept it in, I change the position of it to see if it fits outside the for loop

Comment: Do you know that your 'copy' is just a reference to the original array, you need to use `memcpy`.

Comment: I can assume GetSubstring is valid. I can't use memcpy because it is another function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is supposed to terminate the string:

```
*result += '\0'
```

But it doesn't because you are adding zero to the existing value.  Try setting it to zero instead:

```
*result = '\0'
```

More importantly, your loop is wack.  This contains a whole lot of recipes for trouble:

```
for (; *source != '\0' || *source == source[start]; start--)
{
    while (*source != '\0')
    {
        *result++ = *source++;
    }
}
```

Why don't you begin at `start`, and then *increment*...

```
int i = 0;
const char *str = &source[start];

while( i < count && *str != '\0' ) {
    result[i++] = *str++;
}
result[i] = '\0';
```

Comment: That last part would work except the limitation. I can't set int i

Comment: +1 for "More importantly, your loop is wack."  Among other things :)

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be here: `result += '\0'`. which should be `*result = '\0';`

Comment: Yes that was part of the problem

Comment: @user1798862 please select the answer if it solved your problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.

1. Make space on heap for your substring
2. Iterate through source until you hit the end of the string or you finish copying. Copy characters to substring you want to return
3. Add the terminating character
4. Return the result

Hope this helps

```
char *GetSubstring(const char source[], int start, int count, char result[])
{
    int i = 0;
    char *substr = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));
    for (; source[start] != '\0' && count > 0; count--)
    {
        substr[i++] = source[start++];
    }

    substr[i] = '\0';
    return (substr);                                   
}
```

Comment: I've seen this before. Thank you but I cannot use it.